# parse json object in deeper hierarchy different

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

My JSON lokes something like this:

```
   {
    "people":
       {
        "stuff":"OK",
        "name":"some reason",
        "content" : 
           {
            "name": "pet",
            "phone": "some value",
            "owner": "123"
           }
       },
    "machines":
        {
          "owner": 
           {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "peter"
           }
        }
    }
```

My owner class looks like this:

```
public class Owner {

@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String name;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

I get this error: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`
I made a pojo for the owner, but my problem is that the owner on hierarchy level 3 is only a String and on lower levels it is a custom object. How can i tell my parser to handle the owner object starting from the third level different than before ?

Comment: What are field not consistence get those value in try-catch block.

Comment: Use online parser for correct json parsing and all well be okey: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Use gson parser which will return the object directly

Comment: not sure if i get it, can you provide a code sample pls

Comment: http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Comment: i tried this online tool, but my data seems to complex for it
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the google **Gson** parser lob to create the java object from the jSON

http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

http://www.journaldev.com/2321/google-gson-api-for-json-processing-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

ok i just created another Pojo with the same name + '_' one pojo contains the owner as String and one as owner object. was more easy than expected, there was no parsing neccesarry